# communication between browser and google app engine application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to learn the communication between the web browser and the google app engine application. How it uses application layer, transport layer, how the browser makes use of DNS. Please explain or provide the link where I can thoroughly get to know about these. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The communication between a browser and the App Engine is the same as between a browser and any web server - there are no differences in communication protocols, DNS use, etc. Your client application does not even know that the server side resides on the App Engine.

Comment: can you please provide me some material to get comlete knowlege about them.